# Plot is behaving weird

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some trajectories in 3D. I noticed that the plot function is behaving weird.

I defined a variable named `pos`, which is a 2 dimensional matrix. It has 3 columns, where each column represents a coordinate axis. Please see the complete code below-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

max = 1.0
min = -1.0
cols = 3
goals = 4
timesteps = 20

#pos = np.zeros((timesteps, cols)) # this doesn't works hence commented

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(goals):
    pos = np.zeros((timesteps, cols)) # this works as expected
    for t in range(timesteps):
        pos[t] = np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=cols)
    ax.plot(pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1], pos[:, 2])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

The plot doesn't draw everthing, when `pos` is defined globally. I noticed that defining `pos` inside the `for` loop, solve the problem. It looks weird to me.

Below is the plot, generated from global `pos` variable (after commenting the `pos` defined inside `for` loop and keeping the global `pos` variable enabled)-
[image]

Below is the plot, generated from inner `pos` variable (after commenting the global `pos` variable and keeping the `pos` defined inside `for` loop enabled)-
[image]

What is the reason of for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The fix

Replace the line

```
ax.plot(pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1], pos[:, 2])
```

with

```
ax.plot(list(pos[:, 0]), list(pos[:, 1]), list(pos[:, 2]))
```

and it will work as expected for global `pos`.

### Explanation

The problem is that `ax.plot(xlist, ylist, zlist)` doesn't immediately plot the data. It merely stores references to `xlist`, `ylist`, and `zlist` and uses the data to construct the plot when `plt.show()` is called. Next, `pos[:, 0]`, `pos[:, 1]`, and `pos[:, 2]` do not return the corresponding columns by value. Instead they return some proxy objects that reference the original matrix.

As a result, actual plotting is performed using the data that ends up in the matrix after the last iteration and all the plots coincide. By wrapping each of `pos[:, 0]`, `pos[:, 1]`, and `pos[:, 2]` in a `list()` we force the column data to be copied, decoupling the plots from each other.

Comment: Excellent. The explanation is interesting. Thanks a lot.